# Can Shudras and Chandalas eat meat?

Tags: dharma, shudra, chandala, caste, meat

Brahmins are allowed to eat meat under some circumstances, while the other twice born castes too are allowed to eat meat under such and such circumstances, so where do Shudras and Chandalas stand here? Are they allowed to eat meat or not?

Comment: Brahmanas are generally discouraged from eating meat, unless it has been consecrated to devas & pitrs but no such restriction was deemed mandatory for shudras, varnasamkaras & antyajas. Manusmriti stereotypes low-caste people as meat-addicts & heavy-drinkers by stating that being created out of Tamas, tendency to eat meat & alcohol is inherent among them, while brahmanas being created out of Sattva, are expected to naturally refrain from both. Manu goes as far as to say that low-caste people are exempted from observing shastric orthodox standards because of their inherent inability to do so.

Comment: @অনু could you provide the verses which say that a sudra chandala etc can eat meat or it wasnt mandatory for them to avoid eating meat?

Comment: @Rajam - eating meat is looked down upon. Eating meat that is not consecrated makes one stoop down to lower castes. A chandala who desirs higher birth in next birth should also emulate practises of higher varnas including shunning meat

Comment: @Carmensandiego ok does the same apply to Shudras?

Comment: @Rajam - yes. They too should not eat meat